# Single row Points to Linestring

Tags: python, pandas, gis, geopandas, shapely

I have a pandas dataframe with a series of origins & destinations in the form of shapely Point objects. I would like to convert it to a geodatabase of linestrings.

```
ID    orig_coord                                      dest_coord
0     POINT (-116.2847753565571 43.61722615312507)  POINT (-116.3042144501943 43.60844476082184)
1     POINT (-116.2847753565571 43.61722615312507)  POINT (-116.3042144501943 43.60844476082184)
2     POINT (-116.2847753565571 43.61722615312507)  POINT (-116.3042144501943 43.60844476082184)
```

I've tried `df['line']=df.apply(lambda x: LineString())`, but nothing happens.
I've tried `df['line']=LineString([df['orig_coord'],df['dest_coord']])`, but that gives me

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\...\py3\lib\site-packages\shapely\speedups\_speedups.pyx in shapely.speedups._speedups.geos_linestring_from_py()

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '__array_interface__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-fe64089b1dcf> in <module>
----> 1 df['line']=LineString([df['orig_coord'],df['dest_coord']])

c:\users\...\py3\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\linestring.py in __init__(self, coordinates)
     46         BaseGeometry.__init__(self)
     47         if coordinates is not None:
---> 48             self._set_coords(coordinates)
     49 
     50     @property

c:\users\...\py3\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\linestring.py in _set_coords(self, coordinates)
     95     def _set_coords(self, coordinates):
     96         self.empty()
---> 97         ret = geos_linestring_from_py(coordinates)
     98         if ret is not None:
     99             self._geom, self._ndim = ret

c:\users\...\py3\lib\site-packages\shapely\speedups\_speedups.pyx in shapely.speedups._speedups.geos_linestring_from_py()

AssertionError:
```

Comment: One problem with your `.apply` statement is that you need to pass `.apply` a function pointer, which is the function name without the parenthesis. This is the way the line should be written: `df['line']=df.apply(lambda x: LineString)`

Comment: please dont forget to validate the answer to close the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had already used this to get the Point objects, but it hadn't occurred to me to repeat the process:

`df['line']=[LineString(xy) for xy in zip(df.orig_coord,df.dest_coord)]`

Answer (score 4):

here one solution:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString

o = [Point (-116.2847753565571, 43.61722615312507),
     Point(-116.2847753565571, 43.61722615312507),
     Point (-116.2847753565571,43.61722615312507)]

d = [Point (-116.3042144501943, 43.60844476082184),
     Point(-116.3042144501943,43.60844476082184),
     Point(-116.3042144501943,43.60844476082184)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'orig_coord' : o, 'dest_coord': d})
df['line']=df.apply(lambda x: LineString([x['orig_coord'], x['dest_coord']]),axis=1)

print(df['line'])
```

Comment: There is a missing "]" after the "x['dest_coord']". Thx!

Comment: @TSRTSR wao! its typo error fixed!  which is coming from prehistoric time!!